# Suddenly my Phoenix project can't connect to postgres if my VPN is on — how to fix?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, vpn

I've never had this problem before, but suddenly as of this morning, if I try to fire up my Phoenix app while my VPN is on, I get a bunch of `eaddrnotavail` errors from Postgres. If I try to start my app with the VPN off, it works fine, and it continues to work fine even if I then turn the VPN on, but if I try to start it with the VPN already running, `eaddrnotavail` errors every time.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you talking about Phoenix framework or Phoenix browser?  What is your VPN?  What is the intended relation between your app, your VPN, and your database?

Comment: Can you use `psql` or a GUI app to connect to the same database and is the ability to connect via a PostGres client affected by your VPN?

Comment: @Everett Both psql and Postico seem to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I got a response from ProtonVPN on this. Apparently they're working on a technical solution, but this is the main issue:

> outgoing connections to some database-related
> ports are currently being blocked on most of our servers for
> anti-abuse reasons

> Normally, any user connected to the same ProtonVPN
> server would have the same authorization to access the database you
> are willing to connect to unless there are additional security
> measures in place, so this is not recommended and insecure. Even if
> you whitelist some ProtonVPN IP addresses with your firewall, that is
> still not enough because any user would still be able to reach your
> database through the very same ProtonVPN IP address.

> we are working on a solution to provide dedicated IPs